# Android using inputStream to read from Bluetooth

Tags: android, multithreading, stream

I have written a program that constantly reads from the Bluetooth via SPP and prints the contents in the stream to a edittext box. I have the following thread:

```
myTimer = new Timer();
myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
   @Override
   public void run(){
     TimerMethod();
   }
},0,1000);

private void TimerMethod(){this.runOnUiThread(startReading);}


private Runnable startReading = new Runnable(){

    public void run(){
        EditText _txtArea = (EditText) findViewById(R.id._txtArea);
    try{
        inStream = btSocket.getInputStream();
    }catch (IOException e3) {
        _txtArea.append("inStream establishment Failed!");

    }
```

Now the msg's incoming can be of any size and I want to keep reading until there isn't anything remaining to be read. I tried an implementation where i did something like this:

```
   byte[] msgIn = new byte[15];
   inStream.read(msgIn, 0, 15);
            int len = msgIn.length;
            for (int i=0; i<len; i++){
                out = new Character ((char) msgIn[i]).toString();       
                _txtArea.append(out);
```

But that limits the read to 15 bytes and the code doesn't seem very effecient. If anyone is wondering why i have the following line out = new Character ((char) msgIn[i]).toString();  it's because the data coming in is in ASCII i am converting it to a char. Also using this method after reading all of the contents when there is nothing else to read the program hangs. Does anyone know a way i can keep reading until all of the data has been read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, for those who are interested it is because the stream should be closed before a read so that inputStream.read() will be able to reach -1 after all data has been sent